# Javascript IMG click, slide

Tags: javascript, image, animation, onclick

I'm using HTML/CSS/Java to build an app to be wrapped by PhoneGap as an app, and I think I should use JQuery. I have an image and I'd like it to 'on click' move to the left and then open the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('IMG').click(slide_to_next);

function slide_to_next() {
    $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    window.location.href = "http://yoursite.com/newpage";
}
```